# Built in equality of lists using a custom comparison function?

Tags: f#

Is there a built-in function which does the following?

```
let rec listsEqual xl yl f =
    match xl, yl with
    | [], [] -> true
    | [], _ | _, [] -> false
    | xh::xt, yh::yt -> if f xh yh then listsEqual xt yt f else false
```

**Updated, further elaboration:** and in general is there any way to tap in to structural comparison but using a custom comparison function?

Comment: are you looking for Seq.compareWith function?

Comment: @Alex - not quite, two problems 1) expects the two sequences be of the same type, 2) doesn't short circuit (i think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning Seq.compareWith, you wrote:

> not quite, two problems 1) expects the
>   two sequences be of the same type, 2)
>   doesn't short circuit

2) is wrong, the function really does a court-circuit.
1) is true. Take Seq.compareWith from F# library, modify (or remove) the type annotation and it will work for sequences of different types.

```
[<CompiledName("CompareWith")>]
let compareWith (f:'T1 -> 'T2 -> int) (source1 : seq<'T1>) (source2: seq<'T2>) =
            //checkNonNull "source1" source1
            //checkNonNull "source2" source2
            use e1 = source1.GetEnumerator()
            use e2 = source2.GetEnumerator()
            let rec go () = 
                let e1ok = e1.MoveNext() 
                let e2ok = e2.MoveNext() 
                let c = (if e1ok = e2ok then 0 else if e1ok then 1 else -1) 
                if c <> 0 then c else
                if not e1ok || not e2ok then 0 
                else
                    let c = f e1.Current e2.Current 
                    if c <> 0 then c else
                    go ()
            go()
```

Now, you can send an email to fsbugs (@ microsoft.com) and ask them to remove the type constraint in the next F# release.

Comment: +1 @Laurent - thanks for clarifying the behavior of `Seq.compareWith`, bug has been submitted.

Comment: @Larent - FYI I talked with Brian through fsbugs and there is not going to be any action on this issue. The comparison function `compareWith` takes is meant to capture a formal concept of comparison, so that `f a b = f b a`, which is not possible if `a` and `b` are of different types.

Answer (score 3):

```
List.forall2 : (('a -> 'b -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'b list -> bool)
```

But it takes f before the lists. You can create your function like this:

```
let listsEqual x y f =
    if List.length x = List.length y then
        List.forall2 f x y
    else
        false
```

Remember that `List.forall2` assumes the lengths are the same.

Comment: nice, very close. but i was really hoping there'd be some utility module out there which would let you do "structural comparison with a custom comparator".

Comment: a potential performance issue with this implementation is that is uses List.length which needs to traverse the entire list.